# how to deal with dynamic items that are used on the base.html in Django

Tags: python, django, database, performance, web

I have some dynamic fields on the base.html like the footer text and the social accounts links, but I need to fetch them from the database and send them alongside with each response for a view that uses a template which extends the base.html template.

right now I am fetching the needed Items on every view and send them alongside with the view context, but I feel that this is repetitive, especially if I have more dynamic items, I tried also to save them to the request session but also it will require more code and edge cases.

what is the most efficient way to fetch these items once and be able to use them on all the views that extends the base.html template?

Comment: This is a frequently asked question: the answer is to use context processors or custom template tags.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you I guess this is the best way to achieve what I really need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @DanielRoseman he pointed me to the use of context_processor,
now I have created a context_processor that returns a dict which contains all the objects that I frequently ask for, so it is now accessible from anywhere on my templates.

Answer (score 1):

UPD: if you prefer to use snippets in your case, please read the answer below from @urbanespaceman.

You can use template tags for your footer. The same as we use `{% block head %} {% endblock head %}` to insert to base.html unique meta title and description on each page. 
Create a template tag in your footer and path any parameters in it from your views.

***base.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    {% block head %}
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
    {% endblock head %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
<footer>
    {% block footer_content %}
    {% endblock %}
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

***any_page_on_your_website.html***

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}
    <title>Page title</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <p>page content</p>
{% endblock %}

{% block footer_content %}
    <p>My unique footer with dynamic variables from view: {{var1}}, {{var2}}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

***views.py***

```
def any_page_on_your_website(request):
    var1 = SomeModel.objects.filter(foo=bar)
    var2 = AnotherYourModel.objects.filter(foobar=barfoo)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP wants to know how to set the values of var1 and var2 without having to explicitly specify them in each view. And the answer to that is to use context processors, or replace the whole block with a custom inclusion tag.

Comment: @DanielRoseman good note!
If there are too many views, where the same variables should be, then it will be better to use your variant of solution.

Comment: sorry if my question was vague, in fact, I am not looking for abstracting the template itself, instead, I want not to send `var1, var2` on your example with each new view that needs the same data.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have used the context_processors now and it works just fine, thank you.

Comment: @DanielRoseman which one is more efficient and reusable, using the context_processors, or creating a custom template_tag?

Answer (score 1):

Alexei's answer is a good one, I just want to expand a little and say you can also use snippets for reusable chunks of HTML.

eg.

**_snippet.html**

```
<p>Some html code</p>
```

**any_page_on_your_website.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html %}

{% block head %}
    <title>Page title</title>
    {% include '_snippet.html' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <p>page content</p>
{% endblock %}
```

I like to use this to seperate bits out by name, so I can easily find what I need to change. For example, you might have snippets called `_company_info.html', '_basic_footer_sitemap.html' etc. It would be easy enough to put this info into your header, footer, navbar etc. but I find having the named files makes for simpler maintenance.

Comment: I am sorry maybe my question is not so clear, but I am not looking for a reusable html, instead, I need to not send the frequently needed elements with each view that requires it, so it is reachable from anywhere.

Comment: and what really works well for me is creating a special context_processor for this stuff so they became reachable on any place of my templates.